# Value of Boolean changes when assign to variable - java

Tags: java, debugging, boolean

I'm doing tokenize the line(String).

I have to tokenize literally this line.

`class Main {`  into `[ "class" , "Main", "{" ]`

The progress is like there are conditions I variablized like `boolean conditionA  = (isSpace && isSymbol)` .

and In the for loop I inspect a character of the line. In example above, like inspect `c` and `l` and `a` .. so on.

And Here is problem.

I made a boolean variable

```
private static boolean isTailWhiteSpace = 
Character.isWhitespace(currentChar) && !tempWord.isEmpty();
```

`Character.isWhitespace(currentChar)` in `currentChar` is a space right next to `class` in `class Main {`

Because currentChar is now holding a space value, so isWhiteSpace is true.

`!tempWord.isEmpty()` in `tempWord` is a `class` so `tempWord` holds `"class"` .

Also, tempWord is now holding `"class"` so the value is `!false` . So `true` .

I expected their value to be `true && true` . So the variable holds these result also `true`.

But It didn't work like I expected.

Because I didn't believe my self over computer, So I checked debugger.

[image]

And declaration of isTailwhiteSpace .

[image]

How can isTailWhiteSpace be false?

I also checked the possible side effects, But the isTailWhiteSpace is only used once and never redeclared.

And for more information, This is usage of above code if statement,

```
else if(isTailWhiteSpace){
    tokenizedLine.add(tempWord);
    tempWord = "";
}
```

Here is reproducible code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class BooleanDemo {
    private static String tempWord = "";
    private static char currentChar;
    private static boolean isTailWhiteSpace = Character.isWhitespace(currentChar) && !tempWord.isEmpty();

    //Just for symbol checking
    private static final Character[] symbols = {
            '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', '.', ',', ';', '+', '-', '*', '/', '|', '&', '<', '>', '=', '~'
    };
    private static final ArrayList<Character> symbolList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(symbols));
    private static boolean isSymbol = symbolList.contains(currentChar);

    public static ArrayList<String> tokenize(String line){
        ArrayList<String> tokenizedLine = new ArrayList<>();

        for(char c : line.toCharArray()){
            currentChar = c;
            if(isTailWhiteSpace){
                tokenizedLine.add(tempWord);
                tempWord = "";
            }else if(!isSymbol){
                tempWord += currentChar;
            }else{
                System.out.println("else");
            }
        }
        
        return tokenizedLine;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String sampleLine = "class Main {";

        System.out.println(BooleanDemo.tokenize(sampleLine));
        //Expected Result = ["class", "Main", "{"]
    }
}
```

Comment: And Please don't be mad about my bad english...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and [don't post images of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Why is `isTailWhiteSpace` a static variable? What is `currentChar` when the class is initialized? I'm guessing you're assigning it too early. It should probably be a local variable or a method.

Comment: @shmosel I made `isTailWhiteSpace` static but private because I have to use that on static method. I wanted use isTailWhiteSpace as variable, so It would be better for if condition readability. And There is no constructor. Sorry for my writing. I added reproducible code. Please check that code. Thank you.

Comment: Your static field is not going to be reevaluated as `currentChar` changes. You need to assign it manually. And there's no point in making it a field if it's only accessed by one method.

Comment: @shmosel Thank you, Then It would be better to use `isTailWhiteSpace` as function not variable?
And I think when using if statement it is better to write 
`if(isTailWhiteSpace)`
than
`if(Character.isWhitespace(currentChar) && !tempWord.isEmpty())`
for readability.
Even though it is only going to be used only once. Isn't it?

Comment: If you do, `currentChar` should be declared locally and passed as argument. Or just make them both local variables.

Comment: @shmosel Thank you for advice, Can you give a reference for specific reason? I want to change my style but I need reason and example for that. That would be very very thankful.

Comment: By the way, if your goal is actually to parse source code, there are sophisticated tools to perform this grunt work. For example: [JavaParser](https://javaparser.org/) and [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR).

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm just practicing projects in the book 'nand2tetris'. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

After the initial initialization, you did not dynamically refresh the value of `isTailWhiteSpace` in the code

```
private static boolean isTailWhiteSpace = Character.isWhitespace(currentChar) && !tempWord.isEmpty();

isTailWhiteSpace = true && false;
```

Can you understand this code：

```
String a = "";
boolean b = true && a.isEmpty();
a = "abc";
System.out.println(b); // I think, although the value of a has changed, but b is still true
```

You need to recalculate the value of `isTailWhiteSpace` whenever `tempWord` changes. If I give a and b as an example, it should be like this:

```
String a = "";
boolean b = true && a.isEmpty();
System.out.println(b); // b is true
a = "abc";
System.out.println(b); // I think, although the value of a has changed, but b is still true
b = true && a.isEmpty();
System.out.println(b); // now, b is false
```

In you code:

```
if(isTailWhiteSpace){
    tokenizedLine.add(tempWord);
    tempWord = "";
    // here, tempWord changed, you need to recalculate
}else if(!isSymbol){
    tempWord += currentChar;
    // here, tempWord changed, you need to recalculate
}else{
    System.out.println("else");
}
```

Working, don't have much time, you can handle the details yourself, or you can extract a method to calculate `isTailWhiteSpace`

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is a procedure, and not an assignment.

For example, you're assigning the variable as follows.

```java
private static boolean isTailWhiteSpace = 
    Character.isWhitespace(currentChar) && !tempWord.isEmpty();
```

I imagine, you are presuming that whenever you call *isTailWhiteSpace*, that it will run the assignment statement.
In other words, *currentChar* would be a different value.

What you're looking for here is a procedure, which Java refers to as *[methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)*.

```java
private static boolean isTailWhiteSpace() {
    return Character.isWhitespace(currentChar) && !tempWord.isEmpty();
}
```

Furthermore, the conditional statement can be reduced.
If the `Character.isWhitespace(currentChar)` expression returns true, then `!tempWord.isEmpty()` will, hence, be true.

The *[String#isEmpty](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())* method is just a quicker way of typing `string.length == 0`.
In fact, if you review the source-code for *[isEmpty](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L1531)* you'll find that, that is the exact statement it executes.

```java
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return value.length == 0;
}
```

Similarly, your *isSymbol* statement will not execute its assignment when it is resolved within the code.
You'll have to change this to a method, as well.

```java
private static boolean isSymbol() {
    return symbolList.contains(currentChar);
}
```

Since there are now methods, make sure to append the opening and closing parentheses on their usages.

Finally, to derive a list that also contains a *symbols* character, you'll need a new *else-if* conditional within your for-loop.

I am not sure where you require the *println* for *"else"*, so I added it to the appending block.

```java
for(char c : line.toCharArray()){
    currentChar = c;
    if(isTailWhiteSpace()) {
        tokenizedLine.add(tempWord);
        tempWord = "";
    } else if (isSymbol()) {
        tokenizedLine.add(String.valueOf(currentChar));
    }else {
        System.out.println("else");
        tempWord += currentChar;
    }
}
```

So, altogether, your code would be as follows.

```java
private static String tempWord = "";
private static char currentChar;

private static boolean isTailWhiteSpace() {
    return Character.isWhitespace(currentChar);
}

//Just for symbol checking
private static final Character[] symbols = {
    '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', '.', ',', ';', '+', '-', '*', '/', '|', '&', '<', '>', '=', '~'
};
private static final ArrayList<Character> symbolList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(symbols));

private static boolean isSymbol() {
    return symbolList.contains(currentChar);
}

public static ArrayList<String> tokenize(String line){
    ArrayList<String> tokenizedLine = new ArrayList<>();

    for(char c : line.toCharArray()){
        currentChar = c;
        if(isTailWhiteSpace()) {
            tokenizedLine.add(tempWord);
            tempWord = "";
        } else if (isSymbol()) {
            tokenizedLine.add(String.valueOf(currentChar));
        }else {
            System.out.println("else");
            tempWord += currentChar;
        }
    }

    return tokenizedLine;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String sampleLine = "class Main {";

    System.out.println(BooleanDemo.tokenize(sampleLine));
    //Expected Result = ["class", "Main", "{"]
}
```

This will yield the following output.

```
else
else
else
else
else
else
else
else
else
[class, Main, {]
```